# Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1 in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate and MySQL and facing the problem about query sql

hibernate service:

```
List<RenterDto> list = new ArrayList<RenterDto>(0);
    try {
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlString);
        query.setParameter(0, name);
        list = query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(RenterDto.class)).list();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.error("error at RenterDaoImpl.searchByNamePersonalId: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return list;
```

SQL:

```
SELECT 
R.ID, 
R.NAME, 
R.PERSONAL_ID, 
R.PHONENUMBER, 
R.EMAIL
FROM 
  RENTER R 
WHERE 
  LOWER(R.NAME) 
LIKE 
  CONCAT('%', '?')
```

Log messages when debug:

```
RenterDaoImpl - error at RenterDaoImpl.searchByNamePersonalId: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. 
Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
```

How can I fix the problem, thank so much !

Comment: *One*; **`query.setParameter(1, name);`** also, probable `CONCAT('%', ?)`

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch: I have to replace parameter 0 -> 1. isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just do what the error message says

```
query.setParameter(1, name);
```